# Calculating the floating point number expressed in seconds since the epoch, in UTC for a set time / date

Tags: python

i am currently using the `time.time()` command to calculate the current amount of seconds since the epoch, however could this be adapted to easily show the number of seconds since the epoch for a past date, I.E. `2014-03-14-18-00-00`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`time.mktime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime):

```
In [1]: import time

In [2]: target = time.strptime('2014-03-14-18-00-00', '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')

In [3]: int(time.mktime(target))
Out[3]: 1394816400
```

Answer (score 2):

Python `datetime` module has the functionality to compute the total number of seconds since the epoch for a past date. For example if you want to compute the number of seconds `2014-03-14-18-00-00`

```
epoch = datetime.datetime.strptime('2014-03-14-18-00-00', '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
# to compute current amount of seconds from epoch
total_seconds = (epoch - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())).total_seconds()
```

Comment: This calculates the time from 2014-03-14-18-00-00 to the current time. The epoch in the context of the question is the [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).